# How to run timmer job on all servers in sharepoint farm

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, server-farm

I want to run my custom timer job on all SharePoint servers in SharePoint 2007 farm. How I can do this? right now this job is running on only one server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [`SPJobDefinition.LockType` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjobdefinition.locktype(v=office.12).aspx) on your job definition to `None`.

Here are the possible [`SPJobLockType` values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjoblocktype(v=office.12).aspx).

Behavior that I have seen is, if you set it to `Job`, it will run only once, on one server.  If you set it to `ContentDatabase`, it will run on only one server, but it will repeat consecutively for as many times as you have content databses.  If you set it to `None`, it should run on all servers.